# Linux shell: Detecting state changes on a CSV log file

Tags: csv, logging

This is my automatically-generated log file (continuous one-minute checking of my internet line) :

```
$ cat log.csv

2018-04-27,23:37,OK
2018-04-27,23:38,OK
2018-04-27,23:39,OK
2018-04-27,23:40,ERROR
2018-04-27,23:41,ERROR
2018-04-27,23:42,OK
2018-04-27,23:43,OK
2018-04-27,23:44,OK
2018-04-27,23:45,OK
```

I am trying to make it more confortable for reading by scripting some interpretation method that depends on the 3rd field (line state: OK/ERROR) state and **removes consecutive** values, some sort of shell script that only shows the **initial and state change** for the internet line, transforming the above log into:

```
2018-04-27,23:37,OK
2018-04-27,23:40,ERROR
2018-04-27,23:42,OK
```

That would mean:

```
2018-04-27,23:37,Entered Status OK
2018-04-27,23:40,Entered Status ERROR
2018-04-27,23:42,Entered Status OK
```

As can be seen, leaving only the state changes makes the log's display **shorter and easier** to read.

Assuming the log file could be very long (consider months of one-minute logging), what could be a proper (efficient) method to **script this "interpretation" on a Linux shell**?

I know that iterations are not [considered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) a very good idea on shells, so I was thinking about `AWK`, but I am not very experienced on it.
Loops solutions could be better than nothing, of course.

**Further Data**:

- A similar (but not the same) question (asked by me, too) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48490357/how-can-i-detect-a-sequence-of-hollows-holes-lines-not-matching-a-pattern-b).

Answer (score 2):

AWK method:

```
awk -F "," '$3==last{next} {last=$3} {print $0}' log.csv
```

That outputs:

```
2018-04-27,23:37,OK
2018-04-27,23:40,ERROR
2018-04-27,23:42,OK
```

**How it works**:

- `-F ","` for comma as field separator.
- `$3==last{next}` ignores any line where the third field equals to `last`variable: the command `next` tells awk to skip all remaining commands and start over on the next line.
- `last=$3` saves the third field (OK/ERROR) in the variable last.
- `{print $0}` means print the current line.

Not a perfect solution for any special cases, i.e: if the third field is empty. But it will enough for me.

> Thanks to John1024 on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27812184/1461017)

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1.** Bash `uniq` command is enough when the log line beginning is of the same length or when the delimiter between fields is either space or tab.

```
uniq -s 17 log.csv
```

`uniq` filters out adjacent matching lines, while `-s 17` flag makes it ignore the first 17 characters of each line that make up the timestamp.

```
uniq -f 2 log.csv
```

-f 2 makes `uniq` ignore the first two fields. Unfortunately there is no way to change the default delimiter from whitespace to something else.

**Option 2.** `tr` and `uniq` will work for simple cases where the delimiter can easily be switched.

```
# tab is inserted with CTRL+V followed by TAB
tr ',' '    ' < log.csv | uniq -f 2
```

`tr` is short for translate and will turn all occurrences of the first argument to the second argument (from , to tab in this case). `tr` works with a stream as input.

**Option 3.** `sed` and `uniq` will work for more complicated cases when the log content may contain the delimiter itself.

```
sed 's/,/\t/;s/,/\t/' log.csv | uniq -f 2
```

`sed` is short for stream editor and will replace the first two occurrences of a comma with a tab (`sed` allows the use of \t). `sed 's/,/\t/' log.csv` would replace only the first occurrence, so the same search is repeated twice by adding the same search and replace pattern twice separated by a semicolon.

Read more about the use of uniq:

```
man uniq
uniq --help
```

Comment: I did not know about that capability of `uniq`. The proposed case example is a simplified one, by the way, so the `17` offset could change (i.e: for non fixed-width fields on the CSV file), and that would require more parsing/programming. Still, it is a good possibility since, as far as I know, the `uniq` command is a fast (efficient for huge files) tool. Thanks you.